# Let $(x - 1)^3$ divide $(P(x) + 1)$ and $(x + 1)^3$ divide$ (P(x) - 1)$. Find the polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $5$.

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

Let $(x - 1)^3$ divide $(P(x) + 1)$ and $(x + 1)^3$ divide$ (P(x) - 1)$. Find the polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $5$.

I tried utilising the divisibility laws but to no result. I then tried bujte force to find two polynomials of degree 2 that satisfy both the equations. But still got no result. Please help me.

Comment: Have you heard about the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Heard but did not understand it.

Comment: However, i don't want to use chinese remainder theorem i want to get an answer using plain old algebra

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740767/find-a-polynomial-fx-of-degree-5-such-that-2-properties-hold/2476852#2476852

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What can you say about the factors of $P'(x)$?

Comment: That's a good hint :-)

Comment: Um should I delete the question, since it got downvoted

Comment: But I still did not understand

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The hint/method  is also a dupe - which of course is not the least but surprising since questions like this are FAQs (so one should resist the temptation to add/encourage yet more dupe answers)

Comment: A good catch @BillDubuque. This time I didn't have the time to look for a duplicate - apparently neither did Arthur.